# use find along third dimension

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a 2*3*3 matrix `a`:

```
a=[1 1 1;1 1 1];
a(:,:,2)=[1 1 1;1 1 1]+1;
a(:,:,3)=[1 1 1;1 1 1]+2;
```

Think to the third dimension as a depth value. I want to find the depth at which `a` is greater than 2. In this case the result should be:

```
[3 3 3;3 3 3]
```

Is there a way to do it in a vectorized way?

**My attempt**

I tried the following but it does not quite work:

```
inds=find(a>2) %find indices of elements>2  
lev=ceil(inds/2/3) %divide by the size of each layer. it returns the layer indices on which the an element>2 is

depths = reshape(lev,2,3) 

inds =

    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18


lev =

     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3

depths =

     3     3     3
     3     3     3
```

In this case works but it is a lucky case.

If I use:

```
a=[1 1 1;1 1 2];
a(:,:,2)=[1 1 1;1 1 2]+1;
a(:,:,3)=[1 1 1;1 1 2]+2;
```

Now it cannot work because along the last column I have more than one values greater than 2. Indeed:

```
inds=find(a>2) %find indices of elements>2  
lev=ceil(inds/2/3) %divide by the size of each layer. it returns the layer indices on which the an element>2 is

depths = reshape(lev,2,3)

inds =

    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18


lev =

     2
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3

inds =

    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18


lev =

     2
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
     3
```

> Error using reshape
>       To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.

I cannot see a workaround.

I also tried to use `find` with the 'first' option but with no success at all.

Comment: But you want that all elements in the depth are greater than 2 or at least one element is greater than 2?

Comment: The first element for each 3rd-dimension column. If we use (x,y,z) coordinates, I want the first z for each (x,y) pair

Comment: What should be the output in the second case?

Comment: It should be [3 3 3;3 3 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the second output of the `max` function:

```
[~,idx]=max(a>2,[],3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the logical indices where values are greater than 2 then convert it to double so that 0's could be replaced by `NaN`s. Add a constant to represent the number of 3D slice. Then finally use [`min`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) to find the smallest value along the third dimension ignoring `NaN`s.

```
depth = double(a>2);  %Finding logical indices where values > 2 and converting to double
depth(depth==0)=NaN;  %Replacing zeros with NaNs
depth=bsxfun(@plus,depth,reshape(0:2,1,1,[])); %Adding const representing # of 3D slice
%If you have R2016b or later, you can use implicit expansion i.e
%                depth=depth+reshape(0:2,1,1,[]);  instead of the last step
depth=min(depth,[],3);%Finding the minimum value along the third dimension
```

Comment: Thanks! But I had to use `depth=depth+repmat(reshape(0:2,1,1,[]),2,3);` otherwise I get an error ('Array dimensions must match for binary array op.'). Do you agree?

Comment: @shamalaia I used implicit expansion (introduced in R2016b) before. Now I have added the `bsxfun` version which is applicable on earlier versions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Doing some math I came up with this one-liner:

```
1 + size(a, 3)*ones(size(a, 1), size(a, 2)) - sum(a > 2, 3)
```

Test case 1:

```
>> a=[1 1 1;1 1 1];
a(:,:,2)=[1 1 1;1 1 1]+1;
a(:,:,3)=[1 1 1;1 1 1]+2;

>> 1 + size(a, 3)*ones(size(a, 1), size(a, 2)) - sum(a > 2, 3)

ans =

     3     3     3
     3     3     3
```

Test case 2:

```
>> a=[1 1 1;1 1 2];
a(:,:,2)=[1 1 1;1 1 2]+1;
a(:,:,3)=[1 1 1;1 1 2]+2;

>> 1 + size(a, 3)*ones(size(a, 1), size(a, 2)) - sum(a > 2, 3)

ans =

     3     3     3
     3     3     2
```